# deWiTTERS Game Loop in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I am a beginner and I want a complete example in LibGDX how to limit the framerate to 50 or 60. Also how to mangae interpolation between game state with simple example code
e.g. deWiTTERS Game Loop:

```
@Override
public void render()
{
    float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    Update(deltaTime);
    Render(deltaTime);
}
```

There is a Gdx.graphics.setVsync() method (generic = backend-independant), but it is not present in 0.9.1, only in the Nightlies.

"Relying on vsync for fixed time steps is a REALLY bad idea. It will break on almost all hardware out there.

See LwjglApplicationConfiguration, there's a flag in there that let s use toggle gpu/software vsynching. Play around with it." (Mario)

NOTE that none of these limit the framerate to a specific value... if you REALLY need to limit the framerate for some reason, you'll have to handle it yourself by returning from render calls if xxx ms haven't passed since the last render call.

Comment: Why don'T u use the nightlies? Or at least something more recent than 0.9.1? The nightlies are pretty stable actually.

Answer (score 6):

As a complete game engine that LibGDX is, it handles things like this itself. You can configure this at the start of your game, at least with the latest nightlies.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.title = "Example";
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    cfg.width = 800;
    cfg.height = 480;
    cfg.vSyncEnabled = true;
    cfg.foregroundFPS = 60;

    new LwjglApplication(new ExampleGame(), cfg);
}
```

Now your render loop will be limited to 60 calls per second. As to the actual implementation, you should use a `Game` and `Screens`. The `Screen` interface already has a `render` method which might look like this:

```
public void render(deltaTime )
{
    ...
    updateAllEntities(deltaTime);
    ...
    renderAllEntities(deltaTime);
    ...
}
```

There is only the `render` method being called by LibGDX, but you can split up your game logic update and the rendering yourself like in the example above.

Comment: ok tell me in case of AndroidApplicationConfiguration how can i achived same.

Comment: @jay_singh Have a look at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-%26-configuration and also at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-setup%2C-running-%26-debugging#using-libgdx-setup it saves you a lot of time at the beginning to setup all projects and it's easily extendable. Android configuration works just the same

Comment: @jay_singh Oh, I just noticed that you cannot configure it via AndroidAppConfig. I guess that's because smartphones have an internal limit on FPS anyway (to save energy). My Google Nexus S for example stops automatically at 60FPS

Comment: It seems to me that this method does not use the deWitters game loop, as there is no interpolation. Instead, update and render are both set to 60fps. Is this correct?

Comment: @twiz Yes, you are right. In most cases you won't need a real deWitters game loop though. If you do, it's still possible to implement it within the libgdx game loop.